# Open dataset with historical plates/slides from astronomical surveys (absorption or emission spectra)?

Tags: data-request, images, historical, astronomy

The article [1917 astronomical plate has first-ever evidence of exoplanetary system](http://phys.org/news/2016-04-astronomical-plate-first-ever-evidence-exoplanetary.html) inspired my inquiry, as the question has been on my mind for years:

Where can I find star charts/plates from days long past, or more current data collections.

Comment: Not off-topic here, but you may try asking on astronomy.stackexchange.com too.

Answer (score 1):

For optical astronomy, [SDSS](https://www.sdss.org/) is where you should be looking at.

ESO has [digitized sky surveys (DSS)](http://archive.eso.org/dss/dss) from the pre-digital era.

I have worked with astronomers for around 9yrs helping them with data science and none of them use stuff from really old catalogs.

Hope this helps.

Cheers !

Comment: Welcome to the Open Data Stack Exchange, and thanks for contributing an answer. I made a couple of small edits -- first, notice how you can hyperlink text instead of including a bare URL. That's generally preferred. Also, I added what seems to be a good link to the ESO surveys -- if I got that wrong, please edit again and fix if you can.